Kivy app built using PyInstaller crashes at startup with "unexpected error"
I'm using Kivy 2.3.0, with Python 3.10 and some common libraries like numpy, scipy, pandas. The app runs well in the IDE (PyCharm). I'm also using a virtual environment and have all my packages installed inside it.
I use PyInstaller to build either a one-folder app or a one-file app. I've tried both. There are no errors in the build process.
But, when I try to run the app, there is a startup screen which shows some initialization, and then it says, "unexpected error" and crashes within a second. I cannot even take a screenshot to see the details.
Not sure if I'm missing something in my SPEC file. This one is for the one-folder build.
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

a = Analysis(
    ['C:\\kivy_venv\\Prototype\\Prototype.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='Prototype',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe, Tree('C:\\kivy_venv\\Prototype\\'),
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='Prototype',
)

I don't have any data files or any such thing to include. I'm just using kivy.storage.jsonstore  so it generates one JSON file. Should I include that explicitly? I see it's already included in the dist\..\_internal folder.

Are you using the '--windowed' option? Try building without that option and run your 'exe' file from a command line to see the errors. See the documentation.

@JohnAnderson thank you for your help. I am not using the '--windowed' option. But running from the command line showed me the errors and I was able to fix them.
Another question - how do I suppress the console window when the standalone app is running?

I believe that is what the --windowed option does.

Actually, I found out it's the --noconsole option. @JohnAnderson
